# How do you read the rotation of a cinemachine camera?

Tags: controller, rotation, cinemachine

I would like to be able to read the rotation of a cinemachine camera so that I can set other objects to match its rotation as it moves.

I'm trying to make a 1st person controller using cinemachine and I want to match the Y axis rotation of the player's body to the cinemachine camera's Y axis rotation so that I can apply WASD movement to the body and have it match the camera's orientation. I currently have the camera set as the child of the player's body.